# Updating app every 10 minutes within a beacon region

Tags: ios, core-location, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

iBeacon and iOS devices can update the app based on didEnterRegion and didExitRegion. How do I update the app when it's within the region. Let's say I want to update the app every 10 minutes the user is within region. Another thing is I find iOS's detection of iBeacon is quite slow and unreliable if the app is not woken. Ranging it does the trick when app is running on foreground.

I thought of scheduling a localNotification every 10 minutes and POST something to the server but it won't run other processes in the background.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: As to your point about slow detection times:  What type of iOS device are you using? iPhone 4S devices are known to be slower to detect in the background.

Comment: I'm using iPhone 5C to test this

Comment: An iPhone 5C should detect a region entry/exit event within a second, unless you have several other beacon-enabled apps installed on your phone that use all the hardware assist slots.  See here for details:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/04/21/max-beacon-regions-ios.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a beacon-enabled app to run in the background periodically, you have a number of options, including:

1. Beacon identifier rotation
2. Extending background ranging time to 3 minutes
3. Requesting background location modes
4. Sending periodic push notifications.

I describe the pros and cons of each approach in this answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29684731/1461050

Comment: Thanks davidyoung. I think option 4 is the only way that I can see that solves this problem.

Comment: What background location methods that I can use to trigger every ten minutes? davidyoung

Comment: A beacon that changes its ID back and forth every 10 minutes.  Maybe two beacons with their Vcc/power source coming from a 10 minute alternating timer.

Comment: hmm...Interesting suggestion on the two beacons on and off.. :)

Comment: Yes, that is a variation on the "Beacon identifier rotation" option I mentioned above.  You can turn the beacon on and off every 10 minutes, or simply change the minor between an odd and even value every 10 minutes.